# Name for $t \mapsto f(p+ \vec{v}t)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, terminology

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $p, \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Define a new function $t \mapsto f(p+ \vec{v}t)$.  Is there a standard terminology for this new function?

Context:  I am thinking about multivariate optimization for machine learning and it would be convenient to have standardized terminology for this construction.

Comment: Good question. But I do not see how programming needs terminology ? +1

Comment: @mick Might write a paper on a new optimization method which would need to talk about this construction a lot.

Comment: constant velocity movement in 3d space?

Comment: @tp1 The map $t \mapsto \vec{v}t$ is constant velocity movement in $n$-dimensional space.  Then I am composing this with $f$.  I have been calling this a "slice" in my own thoughts, but that terminology is seriously overloaded already.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Im no expert in lin algebra nor vectors or terminology , but how about " internal translation " ?
I wonder what optimization, if it is not secret.

Comment: @mick I don't believe in keeping any ideas secret.  Basically I am wondering whether it is relatively "inexpensive" (using a GPU, etc) to compute the second derivative of $t \mapsto \textrm{loss}(p + \nabla \textrm{loss}|_p t)$.  This should be a way to get some curvature data without computing the entire Hessian (which would be expensive).  Basically just approximate this "slice" as a parabola, move to the predicted vertex and then iterate.

Comment: I would call it "the restriction of $f$ on the line through $p$ with direction $v.$"

Comment: @WilliamM. makes sense

Comment: @WilliamM. I was also tempted by that, but it isn't quite right.  "The restriction of $f $ on the line through $p$ with direction $\vec{v}$"  should have domain $L = \{p+\vec{v}t: t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, while my thing has domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would call this a parametrization along a ray. You do want to be careful, though. Taking the derivative along rays does not necessarily mean the derivative (gradient) exists at that point.

Comment: For example, you would be fooled into thinking $$\frac{|x_1|x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^4}$$ had a minimum limit at $\vec{0}$. But the path $x_1=x_2^2$ shows this is not the case.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks!  I am well aware of the distinction between the Fréchet derivative and the Gateaux differential.  My application assumes that the function is everywhere differentiable.